# Is using "complete" as a gradable adjective ok in some situations?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, gradability

So in writing, I want to express various degrees of completion. Originally, I used "in a more complete implementation". A reviewer remarked that this was wrong, as complete is not gradable. They suggested using 'comprehensive' instead.

However, comprehensive as I understand it is used to express for example additional aspects that are at some point not yet covered. I agree that something cannot be 'more complete' in the sense of being over a 100 %. But I would like to express "more complete" in the sense of something being closer to fully functional, closer to a 100%. I would also avoid writing something like "a higher degree of completion".

I am also quite sure that I have read this expression ('more complete implementation') a lot in technical writing. This does not make it correct of course, but could it be that this is used in certain domains/became common there over time, or do you know of a good replacement?

P.S.: I also considered asking in 'writing.stackexchange' but it seems they are not interested in specific grammar questions.

Comment: While I don't think technical readers care that "a more complete implementation" is like *more unique*, I'd use *more comprehensive*, *improved*, *richer*, *enhanced* or such if I cared.

Comment: I would consider this a stylistic concern and thus subject to opinion. Other writers have used *complete* as a gradable adjective, but you'll have a subset of editors and readers reacting because they think something can only be *complete* or *not complete* and thus prefer *closer to completion* or *closer to full implementation*.

Comment: incomplete versus complete, and thorough, a thorough implementation. Also, I'd be wary of gradable. adjectives don't have grades, but they might have degrees of something.

Comment: There are a few truly ungradable adjectives in English; *main* is one of them. Nobody says that Penn Station in New York is more main (or mainer?) than Grand Central Station. But *complete* is not truly ungradable. I'd suggest using *more complete* and justifying it to the editor by giving him a few alternatives and explaining why they are all inferior.

Comment: I can order kits that are 25% complete, 50% complete.  I think I could say that the second one is more complete than the first.

Comment: I think the looser broadening is fine here, where 'more complete' is short for 'more nearly complete'. Very few people are unhappy with say 'We'll wait until the lake is fuller') (and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/full) has the idiomatic 'This cup is very full' (ie _very nearly full_) ). See [How can something be _fuller_ or _the fullest_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260896/how-can-something-be-fuller-or-the-fullest)

Comment: Thanks for everybody's comments. Comments/answers are mixed, but as natural language is anyway not 'logical' (which is why over time, there were so many who set out to create a more logical language), I'd say this usage is acceptable.

Comment: We often use language with lack of precision. 'This bottle is fuller than that one' would not usually raise eyebrows, though 'full' is essentially ungradable. It's shorthand for 'This bottle is nearer to being full than that one'. And 'less / more complete' are similar idiomatic shortenings.

Comment: Start by not beginning any writing with _So_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: So be it.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that, strictly speaking, *complete* means that the thing in question contains exactly 100% (or perhaps one should say 100.00000000%) of whatever it is supposed to contain, and that is a yes-or-no matter. However, in casual communication, *complete* is often used in a loose sense in which it means something like: close enough, for the purposes implied by the context, to being complete-in-the-strict sense. One may thus find the word, in that loose sense, applied in a particular context to something that contains anything between, say, 95% and 100% of whatever it is supposed to contain (although an aspect of the looseness of that sense is that the threshold is not precisely and explicitly specified). When the word is used in that loose sense, it is gradable: something can be complete in that sense in that it contains 96% of what it is supposed to contain, and then be made more complete (i.e. brought closer to being complete-in-the-strict-sense) by increasing that percentage to 99%.

There is nothing wrong with using the word in that loose sense, as long as one is aware that it is a loose sense. An argument can, however, be made that, while the loose sense is OK in casual communication, it should be eschewed in scientific and scholarly publications, and that was probably on the mind of the reviewer who objected to your use of the word. Whether one should accept that argument is something on which reasonable people may disagree.

(This answer is essentially an elaboration of the point made by Mr. Ashworth in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

from the OED:

**Gradable**: 2. *Grammar*. *Of a word (esp. an adjective) or quality denoted by it: that admits of comparison or of qualification with respect to degree.*

(and by inference **ungradable** = "that does not admit")

has the example:

> 1944   Philosophy of Science. 11 115   *The superlative implication of ‘perfect’, which should make of it a unique and ungradable term, tends to be lost sight of for the simple reason that it belongs to the class of essentially gradable terms (e.g. ‘good’).*

I suggest the adjective "complete" also has a superlative implication which should make of it a unique and ungradable term, it belongs to the class of essentially gradable terms (e.g. ‘good’).

Comment: An archivist once admonished me that “No collection is complete.” It follows that some collections (of, say, first editions of Orson Scott Card’s novels) are more complete than others.

Comment: So, what would it mean to say that one's collection is  _more_ (or _less_) _incomplete_ than someone else's?

Comment: @JohnLawler Wouldn't a "more incomplete" collection be one that had more potential items missing than one which was "less incomplete"? This would, of course apply only to collections where a "complete collection" can be defined: for instance a collection of the first editions of all books by a dead author or all the stamps in a particular series. It would not apply to a collection of neolithic arrowheads or 16C British pottery.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, really. You can play set theory if you like, but that’s not English.

Comment: @Xanne English is littered with set theory: there are nouns, verbs, prepositional phrases, etc: these are sets - verbs decline in sets, vowels evolve in sets. The question asks that "complete" be put in a set. When a thing is "complete" it has reached its final point - this must be superlative. "Are superlatives gradeable?"

Comment: The most interesting thing to me about this post is the OED's spelling of "gradeable". [Onelook](https://onelook.com/?w=gradeable&ls=a) doesn't indicate any dictionaries that contain that spelling!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am not entirely sure about its meaning.
You quote OED, saying it's a superlative. Right. But then both the quote and you both reiterate that it belongs to the essentially gradable terms. So which is it?
Overall, based on comments etc. I would be more comfortable with accepting an answer that has more explanation on what the quotes etc mean.

Comment: @step21 *You quote OED, saying it's a superlative.* No The quote is from "Philosophy of Science." *"But then both the quote and you both reiterate that it belongs to the essentially gradable terms."* No. I don't do this and neither does the quote.

Comment: As that may be, what I wanted to express the answer is more confusing then helpful, and far from clear.