# Is the adjective "irregular" gradable?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gradability

Is it improper to describe something as "more irregular" than something else, or is irregular non-gradable? Merriam-Webster isn't very helpful with classifying adjectives in this way, and Strunk & White never mentioned it (at least in the 4th edition). I'm out of reference books.

Logically, it seems like it should be non-gradable because I'm pretty sure "regular" is. On the other hand, there are degrees of irregularity, unlike regularness.

Comment: Good points, though *highly irregular* is a standard phrase.

Comment: There are degrees of irregularity. "As he got older, his handwriting became more irregular."

Comment: I'd give it a D+.

Comment: Strunk and White is not a comprehensive grammar reference (it's not even a grammar reference or reference at all). It's just a style guide to help people unaccustomed to writing to avoid some things that annoy college teachers. Back to the point, [I thought this reddit thread explained gradability well](https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/4a9455/being_down_voted_for_stating_the_obvious/)... 'regular' doesn't seem very non-gradable to me.

Comment: _Irregularity_ means not obeying the rules. There are a lot of rules, especially in people's minds, so something can disobey only a small number of rules, in which case it's mildly irregular, whereas if it violates every rule possible, it's extremely irregular.  Like the auxiliary verb _be_, for instance.

Comment: One has to get used to imprecision in even idiomatic English. 'Which glass is more full?' instead of the precise  'Which glass is more nearly full?' See, for instance, [How can something be fuller or the fullest?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260896/how-can-something-be-fuller-or-the-fullest)

Comment: There are degrees to every single concept that any human (or other animal) has ever and will ever have.

Comment: @PoundHash maybe philosophically, but we're talking about grammar here. Something can't be "more perfect", e.g.. It is either perfect or it isn't with no in-between.

Comment: @Zaya Perhaps we should allow it if only to have a more perfect union. You might send back your new tiles because they are somewhat irregular, even if it's obvious they're squares and not triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if dictionaries do not state that an adjective is gradable, the examples they provide can shed light:

> - The company was sold off in a ***rather irregular*** way, as I remember.
> - The enquiry showed that various financial transactions had been carried out in a ***very irregular*** manner. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irregular))

> His behavior as a teacher was ***highly irregular***. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregular))

> It has, however, a ***highly irregular*** shape with bulges and indentations of various sizes ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/irregular))

Context is always helpful in determining if you can have different degrees of irregularity. And of course, you cannot have a **more irregular or regular* ***verb*** in grammar, but you *can* have ***a more irregular timetable*** ***on a more regular basis***:

[image]

As you can see, this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20irregular%20*_NOUN%2C%20more%20regular%20*_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that ***more irregular*** is more common than ***more regular*** in combination with nouns with the exception of the set phrase *on a more regular basis*. Without a noun, the situation reverses (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20irregular%2Cmore%20regular%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)).

Answer (score 3):

"Regular" is itself gradable.

[An example usage from NYT:](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2022/04/07/science/endemic-meaning-pandemic-covid.html)

> It took the 1918 flu pandemic three years to settle into a **more regular** pattern

[Another from The Guardian:](https://amp.theguardian.com/uk-news/2018/oct/03/regular-secure-work-wanted-by-almost-half-on-zero-hours-contracts-flexible-gig-economy)

> Almost half of people on zero-hours contracts want **more regular** work

So there is no reason to doubt that "irregular" is also gradable.